# определить OLE DB provider

Tags: c#, access

Как программно определить установленную на компьютере заказчика версию OLE DB Provider?

Чтобы не подправлять каждый раз строку подключения к MS Access из C# 2012.

Comment: Лучший вариант - ставить все нужное самому.

Comment: Т.е. перебрать все варианты?

Comment: `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbEnumerator`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Определить наличие того или иного OLE DB провайдера можно при помощи класса `OleDbEnumerator`. Для этого нужно выполнить несложный поиск в `DataTable`, которую возвращает его метод `GetElements`.

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
. . .
OleDbEnumerator enumerator = new OleDbEnumerator();
DataRow[] foundRows = enumerator.GetElements().Select("SOURCES_DESCRIPTION = 'Microsoft Jet 4.0 OLE DB Provider'");
if (foundRows.Length == 0)
{
  /*Провайдер не найден.*/
}
else
{
  /*Провайдер найден. Всё в порядке.*/
}
```

Данный пример показывает проверку наличия провайдера Jet 4.0, который использовался в старых версиях Access. Чтобы проверить наличие любого другого провайдера достаточно вместо `Microsoft Jet 4.0 OLE DB Provider` указать название искомого провайдера.